# no match for 'operator<<' when measuring time in C++ and writing into file

Tags: c++, sorting, time, operator-keyword

I have written a code to measure the running time of a sorting algorithm and to write the time into a file but I keep getting 
"error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream' and 'std::chrono::duration >')|"
and I am not sure how to fix it. A snippet of my code is here and the error is on the line with the data file:

```
  auto start=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  selectionsort(numberarray, length);
  auto stop=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop-start);
datafile << length << ';' << duration << endl;
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?
Thank you

Comment: << duration.[count()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count)

Comment: You are trying to stream a `std::chrono::duration` to a `std::ostream`, but that type can't do that. You *probably* want to stream `duration.count`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it was that simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: With g++ simply change standard to C++ 20 with  `-std=gnu++2a` and recompile.  [duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) now have `<<` operator.